# Can not run more than 1 event in Infura

Tags: events, web3.py, infura, python, filters

I am trying to listening to many events from infura but it is not working. Only one filter work, when I add the second filter, this message appear:

```
RuntimeError: cannot call recv while another coroutine is already waiting for the next message
Exception in thread Thread-15:
```

and after about 2 seconds, this error message appear:

```
raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'filter not found'}
```

and The following is my python code:

```
import threading
import time
from web3 import Web3
import json


PROVIDER = "wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws/v3/f5000000000000"
web3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider(PROVIDER))


truffleFile = json.load(open('/Users/a/ropsten/build/contracts/a.json'))
abi = truffleFile['abi']
bytecode = truffleFile['bytecode']

contract = web3.eth.contract(abi= abi, address= '0x000000000000000')


 # ------------------------------------------------------------

def handle_event2(name,event):
     print('the event is from :%s'%name)
     print(event)


def log_loop2(name,event_filter, poll_interval):
     while True:
        for event in event_filter.get_new_entries():
            handle_event2(name,event)
        time.sleep(poll_interval)

def PS_listen():
     print(" I am in PS Listen ")
     block_filter = contract.events.PS.createFilter(fromBlock = 'latest')

     worker1 = threading.Thread(target=log_loop2, args=('Th-1',block_filter, 2,))
     worker1.start()



     print(" I am in PS Listen after start")


def handle_event2(name,event):
     print('the event is from :%s'%name)
     print(event)
# ---------------------------------------------

def log_loop2(name,event_filter, poll_interval):
      while True:
           for event in event_filter.get_new_entries():
               handle_event2(name,event)
      time.sleep(poll_interval)

def listen():
     print(" I am in Listen ")
     block_filter = contract.events.PS.createFilter(fromBlock = 'latest')

     print(block_filter)
     worker2 = threading.Thread(target=log_loop2, args=('Th-2',block_filter, 2,))
     worker2.start

     print(" I am in Listen after start")



 print(" This is the main function1")
 PS_listen()
 listen()
 print(" This is the main function2")
```

Note: I have added my Infura project ID correctly. The contract address is coped from the terminal after deploy it on Ropsten infura.

Is it threading problem which prevent me to create another filter for the next event while the error means a coroutine is running in another mission???

Any help please is much appreciated to solve this problem